# Isn't it unfair that the bad jinns or devils or shaitans instigate humans but the devils are instigated by none?

Tags: sin, jinn, mankind

As far I know we humans do sins because we have free will. But on top of that we are also instigated to do bad deeds by the bad jinns or devils. Now the jinns also have free will and thus they can also do bad deed. But no one is there to instigate them. Now some may say that the bad jinns instigate the others. But if so there will be none to instigate the first jinn to do bad deeds. So I think they did it as they have free wil. So isn't it unfair that all of mankind is instaged by not all of the jinns?

Comment: It wouldn't be unfair, Since Allah will judge us according to our authorization, and it doesnt mean that it is unfair if he has more authorization, Since the most significant issue is related to ِDoomsday.

Comment: No. Read verses [17.61-64](http://quranx.com/17.61-64?allTranslations=y). Esp [17.64](http://quranx.com/17.64?allTranslations=y)

Answer (score -1):

Nice verse. Well done. but anyway I reckon that : the most significant matter is related to the approach of the calculation. Actually Allah would calculate their account according to their option, then logically their calculation would be harder than us. Then we cannot say that this is unfair... –  السید____علی 8 hours ago

otherwise, we can say that it is not fair that Allah gives more property to some people..., but the point is that Allah will calculate according to our options.. e.g. Allah doesn't expect a poor people as a rich people..., and actually Allah would be more strict against rich people.. –  السید____علی 8 hours ago

Answer (score -1):

Well, this question of yours comes under 'ghaib' tag. Theses things happen in the unseen perception of Humans. But to guess, who knows, even those among Jinn, the bad Jinn do instigate the good ones to become bad. As within mankind, bad people influence good.

We have been made known about only one(main) disapproved act of the Iblis who belongs to family of the Jinn. But who knows whether there many such similar cases of other Jinn disapproving Allah either out of their 'free will' or under the influence of other bad Jinn.

These things are unseen and beyond scope of Human intellectual.

Hence, IT WOULD BE UNFAIR TO MAKE GUESSES ABOUT THE THINGS WHICH WE HAVE NO KNOWLEDGE OF.

May the creator guide us all.

Answer (score -1):

-Well, It's not un-fair as You think... The "**Jinns**" are created for this purpose [i.e. Testing the people] they are meant for this... But, No-body was created nor meant to test the "**Jinns**".

-Here's an example: The manager is appointed to manage the workers & employees... Additionally, He controls over them (He can fire them, He can increase or reduce their wages... etc) But, No-body is appointed to manage him nor any-body controls over him.

-Another example: The house-maid is hired & paid for cleaning up the houses... But, No-body hired nor paid to clean up her own house.

-Every one in this life is (Created, Meant, Designed, Programmed, Hired or Paid) for some purpose or some task... He cannot under-take another task nor go beyond his bounds... You understand me?!

Comment: if you can add your resources it would be good

Answer (score -2):

Assalamu'alaikum brother.

Bismillah. 
The first thing I would like to point out is, where is the dalil that says that jinns/devils/shaitans are instigated by none? 
We only need to refer to the Quran and hadiths, and thus, what we need to know about the them are only from those two references.

Secondly, being fair from the perspective of Allah S.W.T is something we can never achieve. His knowledge is beyond something we can never understand. The fact that He willed for a part of the human and jinns to go astray but He is still and always will be Al-'Adl (The All-Just). 
In another way as a human to see it is that He owns us, so it is up to Him to do whatever He wills to us. He created our soul, shaped our body, and even write the story of our life! We are His absolute property.

Wuallahua'lam.